# Switch user UI in Xbox UWP

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal, xbox-one

Is there a way to invoke the switch user view from within the app? Now we can exit the app and invoke the Manage user view to switch signed in users. But I need to know if we can invoke the view from our app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/93093092-fac8-4ef1-8090-9f8d9c4b50ce/mandatory-sign-in-multi-user-applications-xbox-uwp?forum=wpdevelop#93093092-fac8-4ef1-8090-9f8d9c4b50ce).

[UserPicker.PickSingleUserAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userpicker.picksingleuserasync.aspx) - *"Displays a dialog for the user to pick a user account. The selected account is signed in, paired with the IGameController that selected it, and becomes obtainable using the User class. This method is only supported for multi-user devices and apps, and will throw an exception if called from a single user device or app."*